# Differential equation with multiple functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation in the functions $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$ and the boundary condition for these three functions and am wondering whether I can somehow reduce these to $3$ ODEs (instructions ask me to get $3$ ODEs). I use $c_i$ to denote constants.

\begin{align}
0 &= c_0 - a'(t) - c_1 b'(t) + c_2 b(t) - c_3 c'(t) + c_4 c(t)  \\
0 &= a(0) + c_5 b(0) + c_6 c(0)
\end{align}

Can I somehow "match the coefficients" to reduce these two equations to $3$ ODEs with $3$ boundary conditions?